# Why would test screwdriver light be dimmed?

Tags: mains, bad-wiring

So the wiring in my flat is catastriphic. Some things are grounded and some are connected to neutral. Bunch of switches that don't do anything. Open wires because there was probably a switch there before.

I tried to put things in order to at least feel a bit safe. So when checking the wires I noticed that the test screwdriver was sometimes shining brightly, but sometimes it was shining but the light was very dim.

Does anyone have any idea what the reason for this could be?

Comment: Get an electrician.

Comment: A test screwdriver is actually a neon bulb voltage tester? Does it glow on protection earth or neutral, or it glows on live wires?

Comment: Which country is this? Are you legally allowed to do electrical work in your country? Are you permitted to do electrical work in the building? As usually you are not because you don't own the building. Are you knowledgeable and capable of doing the electrical work safely as per electrical regulations? Are you ready to take any legal responsibility what happens if your electrical work causes damage to building or people, like badly connected wires starting a fire or someone dying because of electric shock? Just think of safety of other people and get a licenced electrician.

Comment: If this is a rental flat, STOP! and have the landlord get an electrician.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test screwdriver can make dim light if there's small enough leak from the hot wire of the AC mains. That leak can be capacitive or it can be dirt. Or an obscure connection between lights or other appliances. It's also well possible that some neutral or grounding wire is not properly connected to the earth. Infinitely possibilites, nobody knows by staring the light.

The device is not well specified quantitative measuring instrument and the existence of the question proves that the already given comment "get an electrician" is just the perfect one. Fortunately you asked.

In addition in many countries DIY-fixes are illegal and invaliditate  insurances. Where I live only qualified contractors can do mains AC works legally.

If it happens that you can access only a part of the house where you live the problem can be much bigger than limited to your rooms. It needs also attention from the owner of the house.

Know that your life and house is in a danger if you make DIY-fixes. What about the other people? If there's some around you, they are in danger, too. Stop, before someone dies or you cause a fire. And get that electrician!

Answer (score 1):

Note that protective earth (PE) and neutral (N) have to be bonded in one single point in the distribution box / cabinet. After that you have all three wires separate L,N,PE. After this point a N and PE bonding is not allowed.

The N and PE shall never glow with your tester, but wires that are open ended, they would glow if placed near other wires that carry current - this is so called induction or they even glow dim due to capacitive coupling. If you connect a load  (light bulb) between these wires and N, you will notice that the glow will dissapear.

Comment: In some regions, PE and N must NOT be bonded in the distribution box, but back at the substation or transformer.